# How do I use these types of codes in my prompt?

Tags: bash, command-prompt

My prompt works perfectly and looks like this:

```
export PS1="\[${ORANGE}\]\u \[${DARK}\]@ \[${YELLOW}\]\h \[${DARK}\]in \[${CYAN}\]\[$CUR_DIR\] \[${LIGHT}\]\$ "
```

I want to be able to add the following \342\203\240 code to it either at the front or back.

I can't make it work correctly. The stop symbol will look correct, but whenever I have a long command and backspace to delete the long command ( a command long enough to wrap the terminal to a new line), the prompt overwrites itself.  The lines don't overwrite each other, but when I backspace to the end of the command .. somehow I can backspace 2 additional times ... if that makes sense.  Presumably, I'm missing escape sequences or something, but I can't figure out what readline(?) doesn't like/understand.  Broken example that I would like to fix:

```
export PS1="\[${BLDRED}\]\[\342\203\240\] \[${LIGHT}\]: \[${ORANGE}\]\u \[${DARK}\]@ \[${YELLOW}\]\h \[${DARK}\]in \[${CYAN}\]\[$CUR_DIR\] \[${LIGHT}\]\$ "
```

OSX Yosemite : GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

The full prompt:

Ideally, the commented out lines are what the prompt would be.

```
ORANGE="\[\e[38;5;214m\]"
YELLOW="\[\e[38;5;228m\]"
CYAN="\[\e[0;36m\]"

BLDGRN="\[\e[1;32m\]" # Green - Bold
BLDRED="\[\e[1;31m\]" # Red - Bold

WHITE="\[\e[1;37m\]"
LIGHT="\[\e[0;37m\]"
DARK="\[\e[38;5;240m\]"

function lastc() {

  status=$? 

  CUR_DIR=$(basename "$PWD")

  if test $status -ne 0 ; then
    #export PS1="\[${BLDRED}\]\[\342\203\240\] \[${LIGHT}\]: \[${ORANGE}\]\u \[${DARK}\]@ \[${YELLOW}\]\h \[${DARK}\]in \[${CYAN}\]\[$CUR_DIR\] \[${LIGHT}\]\$ "
    export PS1="\[${ORANGE}\]\u \[${DARK}\]@ \[${YELLOW}\]\h \[${DARK}\]in \[${CYAN}\]\[$CUR_DIR\] \[${LIGHT}\]\$ "
  else
   # export PS1="\[${BLDGRN}\]\[\342\234\223\] \[${LIGHT}\]: \[${ORANGE}\]\u \[${DARK}\]@ \[${YELLOW}\]\h \[${DARK}\]in \[${CYAN}\]\[$CUR_DIR\] \[${LIGHT}\]\$ "
   export PS1="\[${ORANGE}\]\u \[${DARK}\]@ \[${YELLOW}\]\h \[${DARK}\]in \[${CYAN}\]\[$CUR_DIR\] \[${LIGHT}\]\$ "
  fi

}
```

PROMPT_COMMAND=lastc

Comment: it must be something mac-specific, when I try it, I don't have the problems you do (although the colors don't work at all, and the symbols you added render as boxes

Comment: I updated the question with my full prompt, so you could see how I'm setting it and how the color codes, etc, etc, are defined.

Comment: When I run it, I get this: http://jpeg.cz/images/2015/01/23/24Wd.png Can't reproduce the problem you mentioned (actually sometimes with super long command, the cursor weirdly jumps around. Probably a better idea to avoid those strange characters...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are telling `bash` with

```
\[\342\203\240\]
```

that the intended character takes up *zero* space on the command line, when it actually occupies one space. One (not so elegant) fix is to only include two of the UTF-8 bytes inside the `\[...\]`:

```
\[\342\203\]\240
```

which tells `bash` to ignore only 2 of the 3 "characters" when computing the length of the prompt. The `\[`/`\]` pair itself is not actually output to the terminal, so it does not affect the display of the prompt at all, just `bash`'s interpretation of its length.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if your locale is UTF-8, then `bash` will correctly convert UTF-8 sequences into `wchar_t` before calling `wcwidth`

Comment: I knew there must be something I was overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer ended up being :

```
export PS1="\[${BLDRED}\]\342\203\240 \[${LIGHT}\]: \[${ORANGE}\]\u \[${DARK}\]@ \[${YELLOW}\]\h \[${DARK}\]in \[${CYAN}\]\[$CUR_DIR\] \[${LIGHT}\]\$ "
```